# Automatically generated Swift-Header broken in Xcode 8

Tags: objective-c, bridging-header, swift3, xcode8, ios10

When I try to build my app with Xcode 8 beta (after converting my Swift 2.2 to Swift 3 using the built-in tool), the automatically generated Swift header (`TargetName-Swift.h`) has some errors. There are 3 different errors occurring at multiple lines.

For example in this section:

```
SWIFT_CLASS_PROPERTY(@property (nonatomic, class, copy) NSArray<NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *> * _Nonnull CANewsFilterBlacklist;)
+ (NSArray<NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *> * _Nonnull)CANewsFilterBlacklist;
+ (void)setCANewsFilterBlacklist:(NSArray<NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *> * _Nonnull)newValue;
```

Line 1:

```
TargetName-Swift.h:562:90: Too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
```

and

```
TargetName-Swift.h:562:1: Unknown type name 'SWIFT_CLASS_PROPERTY'
```

Line 2:

```
TargetName-Swift.h:563:1: Expected identifier or '('
```

This is the Swift-Code that belongs to the code above:

```
public static var CANewsFilterBlacklist:[[String:String]] {
    get {
        if let data = iCloudStorageStatic.object(forKey: CAUserDefaultsNewsFilterBlacklistKey) as? [[String:String]] {
            return data
        } else {
            return [[String:String]]()
        }
    }
    set (newValue) {
        iCloudStorageStatic.set(newValue, forKey: CAUserDefaultsNewsFilterBlacklistKey)
    }
}
```

I have no idea, what is wrong with my Swift-Code? Xcode does not show any errors in the Swift code. It just generates the corrupt Swift-Header.

Is this a bug in Xcode 8 (in Xcode 7, everything worked as expected)?

Comment: Looks like a bug in Xcode 8 beta. [Please report it.](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rickster said, it was a bug in Xcode, which is resolved in Version 8.0 beta 2.
https://openradar.appspot.com/26786528

Comment: Any update on this.? I'm getting similar error on Xcode10. Any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score -1):

was having the same issue and noticed that the method was using objects not available in Objective-C, in your case

> [[String:String]]

is swift specific, try to use NSDictionary instead
and also not sure if the properties in swift can be converted to Objective-C equivalent directly by the compiler through the generated header,

if you are not using CANewsFilterBlacklist from outside declaring it as private might be also a fix,

hopefully apple will come with proper fix later